# How to leave characters when using string.split

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to leave characters when using string.split method

I'm using string.split method to add items in array . 
That's how my string looks like:

```
let modalMessage="Hello, my name is /# Ann #/. I'm working for /# IStaff #/, could you please call me back"
```

I'm splitting by " /" character, editing  , saving string with new value and sending back to server. This "/" does not saves. But server reads new values when  this "/# ****#/ templates exists.  How to possible solve this problem?

Here code:

```
const App = ({ modalMessage }) => ( 
    <p> 
        {modalMessage .split("/") .map(text => (
            text.includes("#") ? <input value={text} /> : text
        ))} 
    </p>
);
```

Comment: At least to me it's not clear. can you add desired output ?

Comment: In my snippet ran just fine. Have you tried to put an escape character before # ?

Comment: Please show a [mcve], because right now nothing in the code you show does any splitting, or sending to the server, so you're not actually showing code that demonstrates the problem you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the slashes `/`, you can use a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses `()`:

```
> let modalMessage = "Hello, my name is /# Ann #/. I'm working for /# IStaff #/, could you please call me back";
> let test = modalMessage.split(/(\/)/);
> test
  (9) ["Hello, my name is ", "/", "# Ann #", "/", ". I'm working for ", "/", "# IStaff #", "/", ", could you please call me back"]
```

vs without regex:

```
> let modalMessage = "Hello, my name is /# Ann #/. I'm working for /# IStaff #/, could you please call me back";
> let test2 = modalMessage.split('/');
> test2
  (5) ["Hello, my name is ", "# Ann #", ". I'm working for ", "# IStaff #", ", could you please call me back"]
```